# Reason for type inference limitations in Scala compiler when dealing with partially applied functions

Tags: scala

In Scala, when using partially applied functions vs curried functions, we have to deal with a different way of handling type inference. Let me show it with an example, using a basic filtering function (examples taken from the excellent [Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) book):

1) Partially applied function

```
def dropWhile[A](l: List[A], f: A => Boolean): List[A] = l match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x::xs if (f(x)) => dropWhile(xs, f)
  case _ => l
}
```

2) Curried partially applied function

```
def dropWhileCurried[A](l: List[A])(f: A => Boolean): List[A] = l match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x::xs if (f(x)) => dropWhileCurried(xs)(f)
  case _ => l
}
```

Now, while the implementation is identical in both versions, the difference comes when we call these functions. While the *curried* version can be simply called like:

```
dropWhileCurried(List(1,2,3,4,5))(x => x < 3)
```

This same way (omitting type for *x*) cannot be used with the non curried one:

```
dropWhile(List(1,2,3,4,5), x => x < 3)
<console>:9: error: missing parameter type
          dropWhile(List(1,2,3,4,5), x => x < 3)
```

So this form must be used instead:

```
dropWhile(List(1,2,3,4,5), (x: Int) => x < 3)
```

I understand this is the case, and I know there are other questions in SO regarding this fact, but what I am trying to understand is **why** this is the case. What is the reason for the Scala compiler to treat this two types of partially applied functions differently when it comes to type inference?

Comment: I had the same question ;)   "This works because the curried function gets executed in two “stages” making the compiler infer types twice" from http://www.vasinov.com/blog/on-currying-and-partial-function-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly both of your examples are not partially applied functions. Partially applied function (do not confuse with Partial Functions) is the function of which only part of it's arguments applied, - but you have all your arguments in place.

But you can easily make the 2nd example into partially applied function (and curried): `val a = dropWhileCurried(List(new B, new B))_`. Now you have `a` which has only first argument applied, and you need to apply the 2nd to execute it: `println(a(x => true))`. You can do the same with 1st example: `val a = dropWhile(List(new B, new B), _: B => Boolean)`.

Now as for the inference and why it works like that: I can only assume, but it sounds quite reasonable for me. You can think of each argument in the function as equal by its importance, but if inference would work and you wrote `dropWhile(List(new B, new B), _ => true)`, you'd assume that `_` is of type `B`, however this also is possible `dropWhile(List(new B, new B), _: A => true` if `B extends A`. In that case if you change the order of arguments the inference would change or it wouldn't work at all: `dropWhile(_ => true, List(new B, new B))` And it would definetely make the inference quite complicated for the compiler to do as it has to scan the definition several times.

Now if you get back to the partial application and think of call `dropWhileCurried(xs)(f)` as always a partial application of `xs` to `dropWhileCurried` and then application of `f` to the result of previous operation, it starts to sounds reasonable. Compiler needs to infer type when you already wrote `dropWhileCurried(xs)` because this is a partial application (I'm still missing `_` in the end though). So now, when the type is inferred, it can continue and apply `(f)` to it.

This is at least how I perceive the question. There might be more reasons to this, but this should help to understand some of the background if you won't receive any better answer.